# MapView airbnb ReactNative no visual

Tags: react-native

Any ideas when using https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps
I get a map grid but no visual? I followed the instillation instructions and cant find any errors like mine on google.Here is my code that works after instillation process. Works as in it only shows a grid no map

```
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,


  },
  map: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
});

class Navigatord extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        style={ styles.map }
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 37.78825,
          longitude: -122.4324,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}
      /></View>
    );
  }

}

export default Navigatord;
```

Answer (score 1):

At first you should check all steps in accordance with this instruction [https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md][1].

If you use emulator of real device (like Genymotion), please make sure you have installed Google Play support.

Check Internet (GPS/Wifi/Data) is enabled on your device.

And don't forget add **width** and **height** to styles of map.

`const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0
  },
  map: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    width: 200,
    height: 200
  },
});`